# IGBT failure and protection

Tags: power, power-electronics, rectifier, igbt

I have a 3-phase bridge rectifier (shown below). I am using an IGBT (STGE200NB60S) to limit the inrush current from the capacitors at start up. I also added the NTC thermisters to help with the inrush current. That end is all fine in that the main breaker is not tripping and and the current is fairly smooth looking.

The problem is that the IGBT is failing a lot, the collector-emitter is completely shorted. Its probably caused by a voltage spike at turn off. I cannot capture it exactly as fails randomly.

The IGBT in question does not have a built in diode. Should I add one and should I add a snubber circuit or would a flyback diode on the load be more suitable or all of the above.

What is the best way to protect the device?

[image]

Thanks.

edit 1:

Gate driver

[image]

Graphs:
[image]

Waveforms: diff probe scale 1/50

Vge

[image]

Vce

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When and how are you gating the IGBT?

Comment: @Marla - The gate driver circuit has been added to the edit. I am gradually turning on the gate from the MCU so slowly charge the caps.

Comment: Are you using an IGBT in the linear region?

Comment: @Jeroen3 - Yes on start up to charge the caps I am using the IGBT in the linear region then will switch to the active region when charged.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Can't you use phase-angle dimming?

Comment: Check the SOAR graph for your IGBT. Very few are made for linear operation. Also, why an IGBT if your goal is “only” to limit inrush? There are much better, easier and cheaper ways to do that.

Comment: Added graphs. I'v only 6amps at the moment and 530VDC so well within limits. The goal isn't just to limit inrush, it will also be used to shut off for overvoltage, errors etc. At the moment I just want to solve the IGBT problem itself. The pulses are for a few microseconds each so not exactly driving it hard.

Comment: Show Vge and Vce oscillograms.

Comment: Waveforms added. Taken in linear mode and IGBT is turned off straight after and still works fine which indicates using the device in this region is ok.

Comment: Zoom in to single burst or cycle. Can you measure both at the same time?

Comment: Combined zoomed in have been added. The gate is the upper plot. Also these have been done with a purely resistive load. The capacitor bank has been removed so everything is fine. Its when the capacitor is added failure starts happening.

Comment: Getting closer. Is the Vge inverted? Are the scales way off? What’s the black wide noise on top of the bottom curve?

Comment: Vge is inverted, probes were probably reversed. The black noise is just the previous signal(s), the scope triggering. The plot before it shows it cleaner. Scale is 1/50 on probe

Comment: So there is very little current  going through the device so I'm not driving it hard. I run the pulsing sequence gradually over a few 20/30 seconds and the voltage gradually increases to about 500V on the caps. When the sequence is over the IGBT turns off and is not functioning anymore. Any ideas why this is happening??